# WPF:DataGridTemplateColumn on Windows server 2003/2008

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGridTemplateColumn` :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn CellStyle="{x:Null}" Width="85" Header="{Extentions:DisplayName Type=Type:StandardClass, PropertyName=ProductKind}">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=viewSourceDataGrid, Path=DataContext.ProductKindCollection}" 
                                      DisplayMemberPath="Title" Style="{x:Null}"
                                      SelectedValue="{Binding ProductKind, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                        </DataTemplate>

                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock
                                      Text="{Binding ProductKind.Title, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And also tried :

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="{Extentions:DisplayName Type=Type:StandardClass, PropertyName=ProductKind}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Title"
                                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ProductKindID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource EditBaseStyle}">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ElementName=viewSourceDataGrid, Path=DataContext.ProductKindCollection}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource EditBaseStyle}">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ElementName=viewSourceDataGrid, Path=DataContext.ProductKindCollection}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Everything works fine on win 7 but tested them on win server 2008 and 2003 and the result :

[image: DataGridComboBoxColumn]

I removed styles of cell , And DataGrid but still
(as you see) `ComboBox` items doesn't appear

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: @Anatoliy Nikolaev: just added

Comment: Have you tested the program under other operating systems? (Windows XP, Windows 8).

Comment: @Anatoliy Nikolaev: No i didn't, but tested on 2 win 7s

Comment: @Anatoliy Nikolaev:solved but I don't know the cause!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally tested `RelativeSource`  instead of `ElementName`.

And after a day of time wasting worked fine on `Win Server`!!

Solution !!:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn CellStyle="{x:Null}" Width="85" Header="{Extentions:DisplayName Type=Type:StandardClass, PropertyName=ProductKind}">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ProductKindCollection,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="Title" Style="{x:Null}"
                                      SelectedValue="{Binding ProductKind, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                        </DataTemplate>

                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock
                                      Text="{Binding ProductKind.Title, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```